# how to loop in byte array in objc

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
  unsigned int bytes[] = {153, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4};
```

i used this

```
for(id b in bytes){

      }
```

got an erro like

> The type 'unsigned int *' is not a pointer to a fast-enumerable object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're using as an example is just plain old C:

> unsigned int bytes[] = {153, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4};

So to work with `bytes` you'd need to do things the plain old C way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(bytes); i++) {
    // do something with bytes[i]
}
```

If you want to do things using Objective-C's features, you'd use NSArray and NSNumber:

```
NSArray<NSNumber*> *numbers = @[@(153), @(3), @(1), @(0), @(0), @(4)];
```

and then you can use fast iteration:

```
for (NSNumber *number in numbers) {
    //do something with number
}
```

> The type 'unsigned int *' is not a pointer to a fast-enumerable object

You get that error because `for...in` is an Objective-C construction that only works with objects that support `NSFastEnumeration`. See the NSHipster post on [NSFastEnumeration/NSEnumerator](https://nshipster.com/enumerators/) for a more extensive explanation.

Answer (score 1):

One method...

```
unsigned int bytes[] = {153, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4};
int count = sizeof(bytes) / sizeof(unsigned int);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%u", bytes[i]);
}
```